# Converting a n-bytes array to integer with ByteBuffer

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer

I need to convert arbitrary sized byte arrays to a `short`/`int`/`long`.
This means I could receive `3` bytes to be converted to `int`:

```
final byte[] bytes = { 0b0000, 0b0000, 0b1111 }; // 15 - big endian
final int value = doConversion(bytes);
```

Thus, I'm trying to come up with a generic function.

`ByteBuffer` conversions works great when you have arrays of a size that exactly represent a `short`, `int`, `long` value. But what if I have an `int` represented as a single byte?

```
final byte[] bytes = { 0b1111 }; // 15
```

It seems converting such a byte array to an `int` using a `ByteBuffer` requires resizing the array and padding it.
Things get even more complicated with a negative value, as the padding needs to be done with the *most significant bit*.

```
final byte[] bytes = { (byte) 0b11110001 }; // -15 stored as two's complement
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this task, or should I just use custom code?
An example could be, in Kotlin, using extension functions:

```
fun ByteArray.toShort(byteOrder: ByteOrder = LITTLE, signed: Boolean = true): Short =
    toInteger(Short.SIZE_BYTES, byteOrder, signed).toShort()

fun ByteArray.toInt(byteOrder: ByteOrder = LITTLE, signed: Boolean = true): Int =
    toInteger(Int.SIZE_BYTES, byteOrder, signed).toInt()

fun ByteArray.toLong(byteOrder: ByteOrder = LITTLE, signed: Boolean = true): Long =
    toInteger(Long.SIZE_BYTES, byteOrder, signed)

private fun ByteArray.toInteger(
     typeBytes: Int /* 2, 4, 8 */,
     byteOrder: ByteOrder /* little, big */, 
     signed: Boolean,
): Long {
    // Checks omitted...

    // If the byte array is bigger than the type bytes, it needs to be truncated
    val bytes =
        if (size > typeBytes) {
            if (byteOrder == LITTLE) {
                copyOf(typeBytes)
            } else {
                copyOfRange(size - typeBytes, size)
            }
        } else {
            copyOf()
        }

    val negative =
        signed && (this[if (byteOrder == LITTLE) bytes.size - 1 else 0]).toInt() and 0b1000000 != 0

    if (!negative) {
        return bytes.absoluteToLong(byteOrder)
    }

    // The number is stored as two's complement.
    // Thus we invert each byte and then sum 1 to obtain the absolute value
    for (i in bytes.indices) {
        bytes[i] = bytes[i].inv()
    }

    return -(bytes.absoluteToLong(byteOrder) + 1)
}

private fun ByteArray.absoluteToLong(byteOrder: ByteOrder): Long {
    var result = 0L
    var shift = 8 * (size - 1)
    val range =
        if (byteOrder == LITTLE) {
            size - 1 downTo 0
        } else {
            0 until size
        }

    for (i in range) {
        result = (this[i].toInt() and 0b11111111).toLong() shl shift or result
        shift -= 8
    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BigInteger class has a constructor that's convenient for this use case. Example:

```
byte[] bytes = { 0b1111 }; 
int value = new BigInteger(bytes).intValue();
```

It does "sign-extension" for you: if the first byte value in the array is negative, the end result is negative.

It has also methods to retrieve the value as the other number types (short, long, ...).

Comment: Thanks! I assume the accepted bytes need to be always in big endian. Also (maybe off topic), what about unsigned values? e.g. 255 represented as a single byte.

Comment: Noticed the update. Also maybe to add how to consider signed/unsigned values. e.g.
`byte[] bytes = { (byte) 0b11111111 } // 255 as a single byte` would be converted using  `new BigInteger(bytes).intValue() & 0xFF`.

Comment: correct, it assumes a big endian order. As for unsigned, I haven't tested it but adding a zero byte as padding should work.

Comment: But applying the two's complements will simply change the sign. Example, `new BigInteger(new byte[] {(byte) 0b11111111} /* 255 */).intValue()` will return `-1`, and applying two's complement will simply make it `1`. Maybe I misunderstood your point

Comment: Oh, ok, I see you redacted. No problem!

Comment: When you construct a bigint from {255, 255} you get -1, the same as when constructing from {255}. The information on the original number of bytes is lost, so that approach wasn't going to work